# How to customize Recharts Scatter circle size

Tags: javascript, recharts, react-charts

I wanted to customize Recharts  Scatter circle size. Is there any docs for all possible custom options?

```
    <ScatterChart
            width={400}
            height={400}
            margin={{
                top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 20, left: 20,
            }}
        >
            <CartesianGrid />
            <XAxis type="number" dataKey="x" name="stature" unit="cm" />
            <YAxis type="number" dataKey="y" name="weight" unit="kg" />
            <Tooltip cursor={{ strokeDasharray: '3 3' }} />
            **<Scatter name="A school" data={data} fill="#8884d8" />**
        </ScatterChart>
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding a z-axis changes the size of the circle. If you want all of them to be the same size do this similar to the xaxis or yaxis...

```
<ZAxis range={[30, 31]} />
```

Changing the range first number will change the size of all the circles.

If you want the circles to be different sizes depending on a piece of data, follow the link provided and below. It is a perfect example of this.
https://recharts.org/en-US/examples/ThreeDimScatterChart

Answer (score -1):

You can customize the size of the circles by adding a zAxis.  Here's an example from the docs.
https://recharts.org/en-US/examples/ThreeDimScatterChart

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.